# How to run airflow DAG with conditional tasks

Tags: python, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

There are total 6 tasks are there.These tasks need to get execute based on one field's(**flag_value**) value which is coming in input json.
If the value of **flag_value** is true then all tasks need to get execute in such a way that ,
First task1 then parallell to (task2 & task3 together), parallell to task4, parallell to task5.
Once all this finishes then task6.
Since am new to airflow and DAG i dont know how to run for this condition.

If the value of **flag_value** is false then the order is sequential only
task_1 >> task_4 >> task_5 >> task_6.

Below is my code for the DAG.

```
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import datetime
from airflow.providers.databricks.operators.databricks import DatabricksSubmitRunOperator


default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False
}

dag = DAG('DAG_FOR_TEST',default_args=default_args,schedule_interval=None,max_active_runs=3, start_date=datetime(2020, 7, 8)) 


#################### CREATE TASK #####################################   

task_1 = DatabricksSubmitRunOperator(
    task_id='task_1',
    databricks_conn_id='connection_id_details',
    existing_cluster_id='{{ dag_run.conf.clusterId }}',
    libraries= [
        {
        'jar': 'dbfs:/task_1/task_1.jar'
        }        
        ],
    spark_jar_task={
        'main_class_name': 'com.task_1.driver.TestClass1',
        'parameters' : [
            '{{ dag_run.conf.json }}'       
        ]
    }
)



    
task_2 = DatabricksSubmitRunOperator(
    task_id='task_2',
    databricks_conn_id='connection_id_details',
    existing_cluster_id='{{ dag_run.conf.clusterId }}',   
    libraries= [
        {
        'jar': 'dbfs:/task_2/task_2.jar'
        }        
        ],
    spark_jar_task={
        'main_class_name': 'com.task_2.driver.TestClass2',
        'parameters' : [
            '{{ dag_run.conf.json }}'                               
        ]
    }
)
    
task_3 = DatabricksSubmitRunOperator(
    task_id='task_3',
    databricks_conn_id='connection_id_details',
    existing_cluster_id='{{ dag_run.conf.clusterId }}',   
    libraries= [
        {
        'jar': 'dbfs:/task_3/task_3.jar'
        }        
        ],
    spark_jar_task={
        'main_class_name': 'com.task_3.driver.TestClass3',
        'parameters' : [
            '{{ dag_run.conf.json }}'   
        ]
    }
) 

task_4 = DatabricksSubmitRunOperator(
    task_id='task_4',
    databricks_conn_id='connection_id_details',
    existing_cluster_id='{{ dag_run.conf.clusterId }}',
    libraries= [
        {
        'jar': 'dbfs:/task_4/task_4.jar'
        }        
        ],
    spark_jar_task={
        'main_class_name': 'com.task_4.driver.TestClass4',
        'parameters' : [
            '{{ dag_run.conf.json }}'   
        ]
    }
) 

task_5 = DatabricksSubmitRunOperator(
    task_id='task_5',
    databricks_conn_id='connection_id_details',
    existing_cluster_id='{{ dag_run.conf.clusterId }}',
    libraries= [
        {
        'jar': 'dbfs:/task_5/task_5.jar'
        }        
        ],
    spark_jar_task={
        'main_class_name': 'com.task_5.driver.TestClass5',
        'parameters' : [
            'json ={{ dag_run.conf.json }}' 
        ]
    }
) 

task_6 = DatabricksSubmitRunOperator(
    task_id='task_6',
    databricks_conn_id='connection_id_details',
    existing_cluster_id='{{ dag_run.conf.clusterId }}',
    libraries= [
        {
        'jar': 'dbfs:/task_6/task_6.jar'
        }        
        ],
    spark_jar_task={
        'main_class_name': 'com.task_6.driver.TestClass6',
        'parameters' : ['{{ dag_run.conf.json }}'   
        ]
    }
) 


flag_value='{{ dag_run.conf.json.flag_value }}'

#################### ORDER OF OPERATORS ###########################  

if flag_value == 'true':
    
    task_1.dag = dag
    task_2.dag = dag
    task_3.dag = dag
    task_4.dag = dag
    task_5.dag = dag
    task_6.dag = dag
    
    task_1  >> [task_2 , task_3] >> [task_4] >> [task_5]  >> task_6    // Not sure correct 
else:
    task_1.dag = dag
    task_4.dag = dag
    task_5.dag = dag
    task_6.dag = dag
    
    task_1 >> task_4 >> task_5 >> task_6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, dependency is not correct, this should work:

```
task_1 >> [task_2 , task_3] >> task_4 >> task_5  >> task_6
```

It is not possible to order tasks with `list_1 >> list_2`, but there are helper methods to provide this, see: [cross_downstream](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/models/baseoperator.py#L1394).

For branching, you can use `BranchPythonOperator` with changing [trigger rules](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/concepts.html#trigger-rules) of your tasks. Not sure about the following code, it could have minor errors, but the idea here works.

```
task_4.trigger_rule = "none_failed"

dummy = DummyOperator(task_id="dummy", dag=dag)

branch = BranchPythonOperator(
    task_id="branch",
    # jinja template returns string "True" or "False"
    python_callable=lambda f: ["task_2" , "task_3"] if f == "True" else "dummy",
    op_kwargs={"f": flag_value},
    dag=dag)

task_1 >> branch
branch >> [task_2 , task_3, dummy] >> task_4
task_4 >> task_5 >> task_6
```

There could be better ways to do it.

Comment: Thank you so much @mustafagok for the answer . But what i need is first task1 need to run. After that 4 tasks need to run in  parallel way means (task2 & task3 together),
parallell to task4, parallell to task5. Once all this finishes then task6 need to run.

Comment: first task_1 is running. I don't understand after that. but you can easily change the order or manipulate, just try it and see graph view, if it is not correct, change. I can try to help if you describe by drawing, or more detailed. Is 2-3-4 and 5 all parallel?

Comment: Task1 parallel  ----> [Task2 &Task3]
  parallel ----> Task4
  parallel ----> Task5
  After all executes Task6

Comment: not sure, what do you mean by parallel with arrows.
if 2-3-4-5 parallel: `task_1 >> branch >> [task_2, task_3, task_4, task_5] >> task_6`

if (2&3)-4-5 parallel: `task_1 >> branch >> [task_2, task_4, task_5]` 
`task_2 >> task_3` 
`[task_3, task_4, task_5] >> task_6` 

if you try different versions, you will find the graph you need.